# Is it good to store User Settings on seperate files without having a database?

Tags: php, database, text-files

I'm creating a web application, (actually my first Web App, I've been working on C# and other desktop oriented programming languages previously). One of my college said that usage of separate files for data storage is easier to access from different platforms (Though as I understand it is hard to move the data from one place to another). I'm currently using Rijndael-128 Encryption for my separate files stored in my server.

**My Question is, is it good or bad to store files separately instead of configuring a MySQL database on the server?**

Comment: Well, you can dump your database and its data so moving your data isnt hard at all. You can also use a MySQLi database, which is also just one file, but you can use PDO to retrieve and store informations, which is much simpler then handling files on your own.

Comment: Thank you for commenting Manuel, This is my file structure by now, [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtPohK5dJqjtiEaSBqrLGjNHALjX), I'm actually managing it very well in my code. Does this look good? :)

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt I hope you meant "sqlite" instead of "mysqli"

Comment: Yes I meant SQLite sorry